# s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'name' cannot appear in element 'simpleType'

Tags: xml, xsd

When we specify the name parameter in simpleType, we are getting an error:

```
"s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'name' cannot appear in element 'simpleType'."
```

eg:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="lengthValue">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="14"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

Is this example is correct? 
Why are we getting an error like above?

Answer (score 8):

Your fragment may or may not be ok, depending on its context.  Since you're getting the given error, it would appear that your context is a local, nested definition, where `@name` is not allowed.

**xs:simpleType MAY be given a name when used globally.  This is ok:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="lengthValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="14"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**xs:simpleType may NOT be given a name when used globally.  This is NOT ok:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="e">
    <xs:simpleType name="lengthValue">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="14"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## To solve the problem:

Either

- remove the name attribute, or
- make the definition of `lengthValue` be global, and reference it
  using `@type`:

**Here is an example of how to use `@name` with `xs:simpleType`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="lengthValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="14"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="e" type="lengthValue"/>
</xs:schema>
```